# How do I add the chapters title in Pages (Mac)?

Tags: pages

I can add date, links, page numbers, but I would like to display as well the chapter titles in the header and it should be updated automatically when a chapter's title changes. Any ideas?
I'm using pages 10.2 (7028.0.88)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bad news but there is no way to automater this in Pages. The best you can do is to edit the header or footer and to copy and paste the chapter title.  But if you change the chapter title you will have to redo the process.

Comment: ok thanks would be a good feature however..